# How can we use a bot to check with SSRS if the reports ready to view in certain time intervals

Tags: reporting-services, botframework

How can we use a "bot" to check with SSRS if the reports are ready to view in certain period of time intervals. for example like every 3 minutes the bot will check with SSRS if the reports are ready. If the reports are ready the bot can send a message back to client saying the reports ready to view.
Thanks

Comment: What is your definition of a report being "ready"?

Comment: Do you want to make a bot work as time triggered background task to detect if the reports are ready? You had better to explain more details about interaction between users, bot and SSRS, which would help understand your requirments.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure why you want to do this, but you can track every execution of every report in SSRS via the `ReportServer` database.  You can have a look through the database and roll your own script, though there is already a helpful view available called `ExecutionLog3`, which holds the report name, user that ran it, when, with which parameters set, the render type, execution failure/success, etc.